# How to sort a paginated collection in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-8

I have a scenario in laravel where in i need to sort a collection after modifying a paginated collection. I have to first get the result of a query, paginate it, then compute distance between two points and then order the collection by distance. However, when i sort the collection, i lose the pagination of the collection and the model changes.

Below is the function when no sorting is applied after the collection is paginated

```
   function testgetrequest(Request $request)
{

    //get the list of all service providers
    $serviceproviders = Users::from('users')
        ->join('serviceproviders', 'users.id', '=', 'serviceproviders.user_id')
        ->join('addresses', 'addresses.service_id', '=', 'serviceproviders.user_id')
        ->select(
            'users.id',
            'addresses.latitude',
            'addresses.longitude',
            'addresses.address',
            'users.first_name'
        )
        ->groupBy('users.id')
        ->paginate(3);

    $spcount = 0;
    //compute distance for every service provider
    foreach ($serviceproviders as $key => $serviceprovider) {
        $spcount = $spcount + 1;
        $distance = 0;
         if ($serviceprovider->address && $serviceprovider->latitude && $serviceprovider->longitude ) {
            $add2 = $serviceprovider->address;
            $lat2 = $serviceprovider->latitude;
            $lng2 = $serviceprovider->longitude;
            $distance = (new ServiceProvidersController)->computeDistance($request->lat1, $request->lng1, $lat2, $lng2);
        } else {
            $add2 = null;
            $lat2 = null;
            $lng2 = null;
            $distance = 0;
        }

        $serprov_array[$key] = $serviceprovider;
        $serprov_array[$key]->address = $add2;
        $serprov_array[$key]->latitude = $lat2;
        $serprov_array[$key]->longitude = $lng2;
        $serprov_array[$key]->distance = $distance;
    }
       return  response()->json(['serviceproviders'=> $serviceproviders ]);
    }
```

Below is the data that is returned from the query

```
{
    "serviceproviders": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 43023,
                "latitude": "60.1581302",
                "longitude": "24.7385724",
                "address": "abc 3 CC  Espoo Finland",
                "first_name": "faheem ashraf",
                "distance": 7019.59
            },
            {
                "id": 43030,
                "latitude": "60.2054911",
                "longitude": "24.6559001",
                "address": "askask 6  Espoo Finland",
                "first_name": "umar nawaz",
                "distance": 7022.1
            },
            {
                "id": 43038,
                "latitude": "60.20245",
                "longitude": "24.7802269",
                "address": "unknownff 14  Espoo Finland",
                "first_name": "FinTester1",
                "distance": 7025.02
            }
        ],
        "first_page_url": "https://myodapi.com/api/custom/testgetrequest?page=1",
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 3,
        "last_page_url": "https://myodapi.com/api/custom/testgetrequest?page=3",
        "next_page_url": "https://myodapi.com/api/custom/testgetrequest?page=2",
        "path": "https://myodapi.com/api/custom/testgetrequest",
        "per_page": 3,
        "prev_page_url": null,
        "to": 3,
        "total": 7
    }
}
```

This is the model that is used in the mobile app and it works fine. The distance to the model is added after the query is retrieved from the database. Once the distance is computed, I sorted the collection by calling sortbydesc() function on the serviceprovider collection. Below is the piece of code that i added to the end of the above function

```
 $myval = $serviceproviders->sortbydesc('distance');
 return  response()->json(['serviceproviders'=> $myval ]);
```

The returned result is changed altogether with removing pagination and adding some kind of index to the sort which has totally changed the model

```
{
    "serviceproviders": {
        "2": {
            "id": 43038,
            "latitude": "60.20245",
            "longitude": "24.7802269",
            "address": "unknownff 14  Espoo Finland",
            "first_name": "FinTester1",
            "distance": 7025.02
        },
        "1": {
            "id": 43030,
            "latitude": "60.2054911",
            "longitude": "24.6559001",
            ""askask 6  Espoo Finland",
            "first_name": "umar nawaz",
            "distance": 7022.1
        },
        "0": {
            "id": 43023,
            "latitude": "60.1581302",
            "longitude": "24.7385724",
            "address": "address": "abc 3 CC  Espoo Finland",
            "first_name": "faheem ashraf",
            "distance": 7019.59
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me how to sort the collection?

Comment: it sounds like you want to calculate distance in the SQL query itself which may be possible depending on the storage type of your geo-data (lat/long). Sorting anything on the PHP side will indeed remove the pagination (which you can add again later), but it often times makes no sense because the query has another idea about the sorting order.

Answer (score -1):

**Edited**:

Don't know how by I'm wrong because I see `groupBy` as `orderBy` so yes you have calculate distance with sql ignore below sorry:

<strike>If you not ordering by distance is good to do like that because you will calculate distance only for 3 records instead for all users if you make it with sql.</strike>

So here is my solution:
You can convert to `toArray()` then convert to collection data to have advantage of [map](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-map) and [orderBy](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-sortby).

If you need just to do sort after paginated collection like the question, answer is below:

After `.... paginate(3);` remove the for and map the result with code below:

```
$serviceproviders = $serviceproviders->toArray();
$serviceproviders['data'] = collect($serviceproviders['data'])->map(function ($serviceprovider, $key) use ($request) {
    $serviceprovider['distance'] = 0;
    if ($serviceprovider['address'] && $serviceprovider['latitude'] && $serviceprovider['longitude']) {
        $serviceprovider['distance'] = (new ServiceProvidersController)->computeDistance($request->lat1, $request->lng1, $serviceprovider['latitude'], $serviceprovider['longitude']);
    }
    return $serviceprovider;
})
// ->sortByDesc('distance');  // for descending
->sortBy('distance')
->values(); // Edited2 return values to fix the keys
```